# Error #2025: The displayObject must be a child from the caller

Tags: actionscript-3, removeclass, removechild

Hello i am having troubles with a presentation that has some videos on a frame,I have made some buttons to watch each video and when i move to the next frame it's ok,the video is "gone" and i can read the info on that frame correctly but the problem is when i try to go forward, it just don't move, like if it was stuck or something.
This is the code that i have:

```
var video10:Video=new Video();
var conexion10:NetConnection= new NetConnection();
miguel_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,video_miguel);
function video_miguel(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var mensaje10:String="MIGUEL ANZALDUA"
puesto_txt.text=mensaje10
var mensaje10_1:String="HR MEXICO"
puesto2_txt.text=mensaje10_1
conexion10.connect(null);
var display10:NetStream= new NetStream(conexion10);
display10.play("Miguel_1.flv");
video10.attachNetStream(display10);
video10.x= 150;
video10.y= 250;
stage.addChild(video10);
display10.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,nomostrar10);
function nomostrar10(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
{
}
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown10);
function handleKeyDown10(ke:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(ke.keyCode == 39) 
    {
    stage.removeChild(video10);
    }
}
```

I read some answers here but i cant figure it out.
I really dont know what can it be happening.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is: to call `removeChild()`, the child being removed must actually be a child of the object. If it isn't, you get an error.

A quick glance at your code makes me believe the issue is here:

```
stage.removeChild(video10);
```

Because that happens every time key 39 is pressed, it has the potential to be removed twice. In most instances, you should figure out how to fix the error, but in this case, there is no way to fix it without removing the logic altogether.

So you can use this fix. Now, you **should not** blanket use this to get rid of runtime errors. I want to stress that. This is a simple check that is appropriate in this instance, but in most cases you should find the root of the problem and fix it.

```
if ( video10.parent == stage ) {
    stage.removeChild(video10);
}
```

That will verify that `video10` is actually a child of `stage` before removing it. Again, this is not a general-purpose solution and should only be used in select cases where the root problem is necessary logic.